# Concise way to copy array elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to copy elements from one JavaScript array to another. Yes, I know there are oodles of questions regarding *cloning* an array, but most of the related answers create a new copy of the existing array. *I already have a copy of an array I want to keep.* I merely want to update the values with those of another array. Like this:

```
//I already have this array
const oldArray = new Array(10);
//here is a new array I get from somewhere
const newArray = new Array(10).fill(3);
//I just want to copy the values, not create a new array
for(let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
  oldArray[i] = newArray[i];
}
```

Is there some cool, slick way to do that, perhaps using ES6 syntax?

Comment: Wait, do you mean like Object.assign()? That's only a shallow copy, do you want a deep clone here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove from the start an amount of items in the `oldArray` equals to the `newArray` length, and then add to it all items in the `newArray`:

```js
const oldArray = new Array(10).fill(4);

const newArray = new Array(5).fill(3);

oldArray.splice(0, newArray.length, ...newArray);

console.log(oldArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()`

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];

const values = [4,5,6];

Object.assign(arr, ...values.map((prop, index) => ({[index]:prop})));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Note just in case: this usage is mutative

Comment: @SterlingArcher Not sure what you mean?

Comment: You can use Object.assign() as a mutative method, or non, as a recent strugglebus because of that, thought I'd make a footnote to anybody reading.

Comment: @SterlingArcher What is a "strugglebus" and what exactly do you mean by "mutative method"?

Comment: I was struggling with a bug because I was using `Object.assign(arr, otherArr);` which mutated `arr` when it shouldn't have, and I should have been using `const foo = Object.assign({}, arr, otherArr);`

Comment: In other words, it directly modifies `arr`, which should be obvious since you aren't reassigning it, but apparently has caused sterling archer here problems, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with an array as target and an array as source.

All values of own enumerable keys of the array, are transfered to the target array with the same index.

```js
var oldArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    newArray = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

Object.assign(oldArray, newArray);

console.log(oldArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```